# How can I create variables that are accessible throughout the entire application, but simultaneously request specific?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, httprequest

I have a springboot microservice, for which I want to enhance it's logging capabilities. Every time I send this service an HTTP Request, there are bits of information that I would like accessible throughout my entire application. For example, if I were to send a name in the request body, I might want to log that name in several different classes of the application. How can I do this without propagating that data throughout every method or class? I'd like some sort of globally accessible variable, but because this service has multiple threads I don't want the potential of accessing another thread's request information that I've stored.

An example request body might be something like this:

```
{
  "name": "Silly Willy",
  "birthday": "2020-02-02"
}
```

In my application, I want to create a variable to hold that name. I want it to be thread-safe, request specific, but accessible throughout my application for the duration of the request. Something similar to a static variable:

```
//In the class
public class Object {
  private static final String name;

  public Object(String name) {
    Object.name = name;
  }

  public static String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

```
//In controller
Object obj = new Object(request.getName());
```

I know string is immutable and static variables are not thread safe, but I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for. Someone suggested the use of beans, and setting the scope to request, but I'm not sure what this would look like, or if this is possible with a constructor method (assuming I'm going to create a class to store these application accessible variables in).

Ideally I'd like to be able to create an object or instantiate something in the controller when the request comes in, so that I can use this object to facilitate my logging:

```
log.info("{}", obj.getName());
```

Comment: U can store it  in a HttpSession

Comment: assuming you are using slf4j store it in the MDC, or use a ThreadLocal to store it during the request. Be aware the clear it after the rquest finished (that applies to both the MDC as the ThreadLocal!

Comment: I actually had looked into ThreadLocal as well, I think that this may make the most sense! Going to look more into it now

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are in a Spring Boot application, as you tagged your question like that.

Then simply create a request scoped bean like this:

```
@Bean
@RequestScope
public MyBean myBean () {
    return new MyBean();
}
```

Which you can inject into any other bean you want and will be tied to every incoming request.

Your Bean itself can even have the current HttpServletRequest or Response autowired like so:

```
public class MyBean {

  @Autowired
  private HttpServletRequest request;

// do something with the request and present it in a getter..

}
```